# How to use QHash::removeIf(Predicate Pred)

Tags: c++, containers, predicate, qt6, qhash

[Qt 6.1 introduced the method `removeIf(Predicate Pred)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/newclasses61.html) to a number of its collection classes: `QByteArray`, `QHash`, `QList`, `QMap`, `QMultiHash`, `QMultiMap`, `QString` and `QVarLengthArray`.

But how do I write a predicate?

Let's take a `QHash` example:

```
struct MishMash {
    int i;
    double d;
    QString str;
    enum Status { Inactive=0, Starting, Going, Stopping };
    Status status;
};

QHash<QString, MishMash> myHash;

// ... fill myHash with key-value pairs

// Now remove elements where myHash[key].status == MishMash::Status::Inactive;
myHash.removeIf(???);
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhash.html#removeIf): `The function supports predicates which take either an argument of type QHash<Key, T>::iterator, or an argument of type std::pair<const Key &, T &>`.  have you tried either of those?

Comment: I read this in the documentation. Although I'm familiar with iterators for looping through a collection, I don't understand how to formulate that as a Predicate argument with the match condition. And I cannot find any examples when I've searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation...

> The function supports predicates which take either an argument of type
> QHash<Key, T>::iterator, or an argument of type std::pair<const Key &,
> T &>.

That being the case, you should be able to use a `lambda` something along the lines of (untested)...

```
myHash.removeIf(
    [](QHash<QString, MishMash>::iterator i)
    {
        return i.value().status == MishMash::Status::Inactive;
    }
);
```